# Call a smart contract from the backend but have a user pay for gas

Tags: transactions, gas, sendtransaction

I want to lock down a method to only be callable by the owner (backend) but I would like the user who is claiming a reward to be the one that pays the gas for the transaction. After doing a lot of googling it seems this is not possible.

Essentially we want to offer the user an incentive if they use our app but we wanted the user to opt into receiving the reward (thus footing the gas fees) or just ignore the reward if they didn't care about it. We didn't want the user to be able to call the smart contract function to generate the reward directly as the reward should only be available if they perform an action on the app.

Is there another way of accomplishing the same interaction where an 'out-of-band' reward can be offered to the user when he is on the browser but not have the user call the smart contract directly to generate it?

I know we could call the smart contract from the backend and make the reward available through a protected 'mint' method and have a public 'collect' method where we check for the reward but that means we could potentially be spending heaps of gas to generate reward tokens the users would never collect.

I've also looking into Meta transactions but its not quite what we are looking for as the purpose is not to have others pay the fee but the user instead that is interested in collecting the reward.

Any ideas?

Comment: have you looked at GSN (Gas Station Network) ? It is all about rewards

Comment: Hi @Nulik, I have look at the concept of meta transactions but our main goal wasn't for someone else to pay the gas on the transaction in exchange for some other reward, it was more about the 'beneficiary' of the reward to pay for the gas of us minting that reward on behalf of them (so that we can lock down the minting process to an admin caller).

Imagine someone receiving an email of 'You got a reward click here to collect' which takes them back to the website where they action the collect and we mint the token from our backend server for them but having them pay the gas somehow.